# Xcode UIView and subviews

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview

first of all, I am beginner with xcode and programming in Objective-c. I made my app with navigation bar and I have UIView with class Lesson1 and I added new subview Level1 but I dont wanna add new class. Is it any solution how add label to subview Level1 from class Lesson1.m?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to do so. Let's admit this is your Lesson1 view code. In the viewDidLoad method you can add whatever you want.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIView *level1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
    [self.view addSubview:level1]

    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(label_x,label_y,label_width,label_height)];
    label1.text = @"labeltext";
    [level1 addSubview:label1]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

**Programmatically:**

```
// viewDidLoad method from Lesson1 class
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.level1 = // Your UIView

    [self.view addSubview:self.level1]
    [self.level1 addSubview:yourLabel]
}
```

**Using XIB file for Lesson1:**

Drag and drop an UILabel into your Lesson1 and link the UILabel with an IBoutlet on your Lesson1 class.

Comment: Yes I added new UIView(drag and drop) but I dont know where can named it. Sorry but I am novice.

Answer (score 1):

Use below link. It might be helpful for you!!
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Core_Data_Tutorial